# Any closer to moving out of Beta?

Tags: discussion, beta

We've been in Beta for (as of today) [320 days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451).

When are we expecting to leave Beta? What still needs to happen?

Comment: We need to choose a design before we can leave beta.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: is that all? If so, that's an answer.

Comment: I don't know what else needs to happen. But I've been trying to get people to pick/create a design for a while. The guy that is the hired artist Jin, hasn't gotten around to pitching one yet. I don't know if he's come up with anything yet or not.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: so I guess that is the ongoing discussion, starting with [What should our logo and design look like once we are no longer in beta?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/554) and also at [How will the logo and design be chosen?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73)

Comment: As for the design, maybe we could copy and paste from [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)? Joke...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to answer the comments, we will get our design when we will leave Beta and it's not the design that anchor us here. Check [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) and [this other](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) blog post for more info about that.

So, since our stats have improved significantly in the last few weeks, we are closer than ever to leaving beta. The only missing thing is for someone in charge at Stack Exchange headquarters to stand up and say aloud (repeat after me if you feel concerned), "**Okay guys, SciFi Stack Exchange will be out of beta next Friday.**"

---

**Update** :
from [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy) , posted the 7 of December 2011:

> Please let me know what you think. If there are no major design changes, **I'm aiming to launch the new design next week.** An early congrats from me!

So, it look like we will be out of Beta really soon!

Comment: So, there is no reason, internal to this site, for us still to be in Beta, e.g. we're not looking for more questions, users or visits?

Comment: We will always be looking for more questions, users and visits. **There is no exact threshold set**, and they said that they don't want to set one (yet). So we must try to get more and more of them until someone say, "OK, guys, that's enough."

Answer (score 2):

I checked out our stats over on the [Area 51 Sci-Fi & Fantasy proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction-fantasy), and we have significantly improved in the past few months. The areas we still need work on are **questions per day** and **answers per question**. Now, I also agree that there probably isn't a specific threshold to reach, but getting those two areas from "okay" to "excellent" can't hurt.

So, let's ask more questions! Even with all the grants we've had recently (Walking Dead, Fringe, Harry Potter and Doctor Who), we're still only averaging the same amount we did months ago. This is probably a whole other meta topic, but I think in the future I will set hard and fast rules with every grant that have to be met in order to be considered for future grants.

Comment: Yes, it looks like questions per day is really where we need work, we're (8) closer to "needs work" (5) than "healthy" (15).

Comment: Even Jeff Atwood agrees that "answers per question" doesn't need to be changed (http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/809/is-answers-per-question-a-valid-metric-for-this-site).  It's a poor metric.