# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://sstatic.net/scifi/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/scifimeta/img/favicon.ico

We have also themed the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), [twitter](http://twitter.com/stackscifi) account and newsletter template for this site.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

I'll be checking Meta closely for CSS bug reports, meanwhile I'm converting the [blog theme](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/) to the new look too.

p.s. I made the Meta theme a dark theme, I feel since it gets limited views, it's OK. plus Meta = "The Dark Side" right? :)

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: LOOKS AWESOME :D

Comment: I like the fonts!

Comment: I can't get the new favicons to work on the main and meta sites.  Loading your links and refreshing them shows me what the new favicons should look like, but no amount of refreshing is getting it to work for me.  Using Firefox 8.

Comment: @keen does clearing cache solve it?

Comment: Great work Jin. But what happened to the other font for the word Fantasy? It's only on meta!

Comment: @Wikis are you talking about the cursive font? what about it? I only use it for the "Fantasy", and "meta"

Comment: Yeah, that is it. I see it on meta, but not currently on the main site. Looks like the font is not changed there. **Sorry!** caching! :)

Comment: @Wikis I had a cache-related issue where the old logo, including the "Beta" tag remained for the main site.  A hard refresh of the browser (Chrome, in my case) fixed it.

Comment: @Wikis can you hard refresh the browser?

Comment: Jin, @Beofett, yep, both right... *hangs head in shame...*

Comment: @Wikis it's my fault. I normally break css cache on image sprites when I launch a new site, but I forgot to do it this time.

Comment: @Jin I thought you were going to do "Science fiction + Fantasy" on the logo instead of "SF & F." Did you change our mind?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ I did change my mind. I felt that "&" reads better than "+"

Comment: I hope y'all noticed that @Jin made a custom Venn diagram for your [about](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/about) page! 8^)

Comment: @IsaacMoses glad you noticed! there are some other lil details i put in the design, maybe in time you'll discover more!

Comment: Congrats on the new design. It looks great.

Comment: Was there a design reason that the chat "speech bubbles" don't have rounded corners? All other SE chats I use have rounded speech bubbles, it just feels a bit jarring any pointy, though I notice we have a relatively angular theme going on.

Comment: @BenBrocka you guessed it. the main site design doesn't have any rounded corners, so I wanted the chat styling to be more consistent. I've been talking to Ben, our chatroom dev about possibility tweaking the Scifi/Fantasy chat room style a bit. I feel the background of the chat messages is a bit too strong. something translucent may be better.

Comment: @Jin TBH the chat and Meta themes are high-contrast to the point of being clashy on occasion (note the background color for the Asker name comments). A slight transparent effect could be nice...but then I'd worry about seeing the stars from the background.

Answer (score 18):

I love the design, as I love all your designs, but I'm getting a headache being here on meta.

Light text on dark backgrounds has been shown to be worse for legibility ([this blog post](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2008/10/13/why-light-text-on-dark-background-is-a-bad-idea/) gives a few relevant citations, as does [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/527378/113292)) which is compounded by people who have less-than-perfect eyesight (i.e. most people including myself).

While there's an argument that dark backgrounds are great for media-rich sites (so as to not detract from the focus, whether it be video or pictures), Meta is not a media rich site.

Can this be changed to follow the other sites, where the meta site is a gray/washed-out version of the main site? [Meta Bicyles.SE](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/) was a great example of how you made a colorful site work in a dark-text-on-light-background way on its meta.

Comment: Yeah, the color scheme on meta does not look good.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the feedback! I gave this design decision a lot of thought. Normally I wouldn't do a dark theme for the main site. (I learned the hard way with the physics.se initial design, and eventually pulled it). I feel that the Scifi/Fantasy crowd may welcome a dark theme, as long as it's not heavily used. Only power users and mods use Meta. I tried the same on the [Photography Meta](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/) and people seemed to be OK with it. But, if this is becoming a problem for more people, I'll reconsider.

Comment: @Jin Meta needs more contrast at the very least.

Comment: @NickT i'll be tweaking Meta for contrast. I tried not to make stark white on black though.

Comment: Personally, I really like the meta colour scheme!

Comment: @Jin Fair enough, but can the transition and highlight colors be adjusted if the light-text-on-dark-background scheme stays? [This is not good](http://www.twitvid.com/PBROW).

Comment: @MarkTrapp See his comment on my answer. It's a bug.

Comment: @MarkTrapp sure. which transition are you referring to? is it the same one from NullUserException's comment below?

Comment: @Jin I linked to a video in my comment (http://www.twitvid.com/PBROW), but I think we're talking about the same thing: when you link to an answer, there's the highlight transition effect, where it goes from orange to white.

Comment: @MarkTrapp yep that's the one. we'll fix it.

Comment: @Jin we want meta to be inviting, not something where only power users and mods are comfortable.

Comment: @Jin while meta (did) go white->normal, **main** [goes light->dark](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/are-there-any-more-races-in-middle-earth/2983#2983), which looks very bad.

Comment: @NickT this is now fixed.

Comment: @Jin Although on meta it still looks a bit weird since the text is white [(demonstration)](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/994/3442)

Answer (score 11):

### More contrast for many things

[image: Needs more CONTRAST.]

---

### and the vote buttons and up/downvote colors

[image: Hijacked to include another poor contrast example on vote split]

---

### and in the link box

[image: Also bad colors for the link box]

---

Comment: I think the silver badges on the main site (not on Meta, seems fine here) also need more contrast. With the pale blue background on the main site, they're very light.

Comment: honestly there's too MUCH contrast on many things, some of the white backgrounds used in meta are very hard on the eyes

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to what Mark Trapp said, I find the contrast especially poor on the answer count and visited links:

[image]

Also, this thing you are using to highlight the original poster in comments doesn't look very good IMO:

[image]

Finally, when link to a specific post ([example](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/996/3442)) (happens automatically when you update or submit a new answer), the fade-to-white and un-fade is a bit disconcerting because the text is white too.

PS: Probably not a big deal but, the spoiler thing is not working on meta:

> testing

<s>PPS: More contrast issues here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2708213#2708213</s>

I can barely see the names. **(looks like this has been fixed)**

PPS: More contrast issues with links on about me section of profiles ([example](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101/jeff-atwood)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I agree with this. I'll be going through Meta tonight and address the contrast issues. I didn't have enough time to test it thoroughly because I wanted to get the main site launched today. I'm sure there are other Meta glitches. Feel free to post any you see.

Comment: @Jin Was the fade effect intentional?

Comment: are you referring to when linked to a specific answer, the background fades from white? If so, it's not intended. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Jin Yup, that was it.

Answer (score 3):

Yay!

I find that the 5k suggested edit count and the moderator/10k flag count are not very spectacular, as they are washed in an ocean of color. Can they be made a different hue that screams “pay attention to me” a bit louder? I think having them on the right of the mod/tools/review link (like they are on most sites AFAIK) instead of next to the badges would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize if this is a dupe, but the triangle used to open up your user stats (to the left of your userID on the top) is 100% invisible on the main site, and only barely visible on Meta.  Depending on how many badges you have, this will affect your ability to read your name or your rep.

***SciFi:***

[image]

[image]

***META SciFi:***

[image]

***StackOverflow***

[image]

---

As a side note, I agree that meta in general is MUCH worse in usability/readability with the new styling (compared to either generically styled BETA or to SciFi main

Comment: I deeply apologize for lack of freehand circles - I'm stuck with MS Paint.

Comment: this will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Added another picture and expanded this to cover my case where I can't read my rep.

Comment: @Jin was the rep number changed at all in the next build (when is/was that)?  It still looks like Keen's screenshot; virtually illegible;

Answer (score 2):

When adding tags to a question on the meta site, there's almost no contrast between the tag description and the background.  This issue doesn't occur on the main site.
[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: yep that's fixed locally. will be in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome design! Like highlighting in menu. But could you make background for posts with favorite tags more differ from other posts? It is very hard to see the difference of the favorites from regular posts on some screens now.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue I've found is in chat.  When you reply to a specific chat message, to the left of your reply is an arrow that links back to the message you're replying to.  That arrow is now too low contrast with the chat message background color, so it's invisible.

Comment: This arrow is almost totally invisible, it really should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to call attention to the [totally inappropriate use of the biohazard symbol](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/348) for marking accepted answers. This symbol was specifically invented for a single purpose, and that purpose has nothing to do with Speculative Fiction or questions and answers. This needs to be changed ASAP, because it casts entirely the wrong impression.

Comment: Martha, I agree with you, and others who pointed this out. I'm in the process of creating a new shape for the accepted answers background.

Answer (score 0):

Of these fonts...

VarelaRoundRegular, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

...I'm not sure which one is ending up as the default font on the main site on my machine.  But I find it extremely unreadable.  The letters are excessively wide.

EDIT: Screen shot below:

[image: This font seems too wide and hard to read, to me.]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing what it looks like? It looks good to me.

Comment: Sure, just a minute and I'll do that.

Comment: So which font do you think is wide? The one on the title or the body? I think this is fine.

Comment: Both, but particularly the one in the body.  It's hard to put my finger on *exactly* what makes it hard to read, but I'd say it's a combination of the width and the flatness.  In particular, I notice that both capital and lower-case O's are wider than they are tall.

Comment: Interestingly I do not see those fonts... Which I actually like and hope to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The "leave another chat" icon is very hard to see (the little up arrow after "User Experience"):

[image]

The contours aren't clear due to the dark-on-dark coloring, should probably be a slightly lower contrast version of the text color like the icon is on other chats:

UX.SE:

[image]

Comment: this will be changed shortly. the icon will be white.