# What does the SFF.SE logo/icon mean?

Tags: discussion, design

[image]

What is this? Should I be able to recognize it, or elements of it? I'm not half-bad at the science fiction and fantasy trivia thing, and this is just driving me nuts.

Comment: [The logo is an original creation](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy). While design elements draws loosely on fantasy themes, the logo isn't from a specific preexisting work.

Comment: I always thought it was intended to look like a transmutation circle from [Fullmetal Alchemist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist).  In that series, alchemy is magic that is treated like a science - making it appropriate for both the SciFi and Fantasy aspect.

Comment: It always amazes me how close it is to some Wiccan symbology (in this case, the three crescents, representing crescent Moons, but drawn to represent the maid, mother, and crone).  I'm still surprised that's in there, since if it followed a more well known religious symbol, I'm sure there would be a big fus over it.

Comment: This would belong on the main site, although it is a bit meta-y.

Answer (score 9):

Scrolling back in time in the [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag here on meta will find you lots of information about the design and the logo. The question [Design for Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy) incudes an explanation of the logo, which was designed for the site, and some of the thoughts behind it.

Answer (score 4):

The logo is an original creation, but it may be inspired from middle icon of this image:
[image: Weapons of mass destruction]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WMD_world_map.svg)

I discovered this accidentally on Wikipedia pages of [Weapon of mass destruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_of_mass_destruction) and [Nuclear weapons testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_testing). In the image, it appears along with nuke (denotes radioactivity) and danger (denotes toxicity) symbols.

The symbol has unicode of `U+2623` and is used to denote [Biohazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_hazard).

Looks like designer of the logo used something from this to his/her creativity juice. But, its just a guess. Only designer can answer this.

Comment: Yes! The middle symbol is what I thought too! Or a variation thereof. I've always thought of it as "Sign of the Hack" for website cracking and defacement, but only in green with a black background or vice-versa. What an awesome image! It looks great here on MetaSF SE too. Thank you for your answer, I really enjoyed reading it.