# What work of Science Fiction/ Fantasy does this Stack Exchange's symbol represent?

Tags: discussion, design

[image]

The overall symbol that this SE site has selected to represent “Science Fiction & Fantasy” is shown above.

Every SE site that uses a symbol has chosen one that very easily represents the topic at hand. Examples include books for *[Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)*, a 20-sided die for *[Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)*, and a chef hat for *[Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)* (My pick for wittiest SE name btw).

**What reason was this sites symbol chosen for and what, if any, are the work(s) of Science Fiction/Fantasy that it originates from?**

Comment: Ahh, the Meta site. Makes sense to be hiding here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [Sci-Fi & Fantasy Meta Topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/what-does-the-sff-se-logo-icon-mean) on the subject.

The logo is an [original creation](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy).

From the second link (credit to [Jin](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44/jin), designer and original poster):

> The logo for the site is the rune circle around the female warrior's
>   silhouette. It's not actually in the logo type "Science Fiction +
>   Fantasy." I feel this placement sets the mood better in the header
>   image. Its design is inspired by a promotional t-shirt I created for
>   the NYC Comiccon couple of months ago