# What is the origin/lore behind the website banner of Science Fiction & Fantasy?

Tags: discussion

I've always wondered. Its quite beautiful.

These are the things I've wondered...

Is that an angel or some greek god?

Is that an ocean horizon on the shore of rocks or overlooking a blue planet of some sort with asteroids?

What is the rune markings in a circle around her that seems to have a theme of 3 being significant.

The larger circle is a star chart two and what are the wavy lines encased on two circles indicating?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the SFF.SE logo/icon mean?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/what-does-the-sff-se-logo-icon-mean) and [What work of Science Fiction/ Fantasy does this Stack Exchange's symbol represent?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/what-work-of-science-fiction-fantasy-does-this-stack-exchanges-symbol-represen/6391#6391)

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have misread your question as asking about the symbol/icon rather than the banner, but the linked questions do pertain anyway, and my answer below links to the topic made by the site designer- some good info there.

Comment: The question seems broader than just asking about the logo. I'd be interested in hearing more about the design of the images in the banner.

Answer (score 1):

As I posted in an [another version of this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/what-work-of-science-fiction-fantasy-does-this-stack-exchanges-symbol-represen/6391#6391):

> The logo is an [original creation](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy).
>
> From the above link (credit to [Jin](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44/jin), designer and original
>   poster):
>
> > The logo for the site is the rune circle around the female warrior's
> >     silhouette. It's not actually in the logo type "Science Fiction +
> >     Fantasy." I feel this placement sets the mood better in the header
> >     image. Its design is inspired by a promotional t-shirt I created for
> >     the NYC Comiccon couple of months ago