# What is our 404 image?

Tags: support, design

When you get to a 404 error page you see this image,

[image: 404]
 This looks like some sort of runic symbol or something similar, can anyone tell me what this is supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is supposed to be a combination of the site logo and the site banner image. See the site logo:

[image: The site logo]

Which the designer [Jin describes as follows](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/976/58193):

> The logo for the site is the rune circle around the female warrior's silhouette. It's not actually in the logo type "Science Fiction + Fantasy." I feel this placement sets the mood better in the header image.

And the site banner image featuring the Angel of Death:

[image: The site banner image]